# Getting started with JDBC

Tags: eclipse, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I was getting started with JDBC and I was using the video mentioned here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxi-H7359LA
Although he is good at the start, he becomes confusing towards the middle.
Referring to the video:

I have a 32bit Office 2010

32bit JDK and JRE

I downloaded the AccessDriverEngine.exe for 32bit

Then I went to Control Panel and searched for ODBC

Then I clicked on the `SystemDSN` tab and there are **no drivers there**
Am I or not supposed to be seeing drivers there?
AFAIK from doing some Visual Basic, you have to add it there **after** you create a `.mdb` file containing your various tables. (Questions under the image)
[image]
**Questions**
1. Have I done the steps correctly to get started with JDBC?
2. I have to create a database in Access first, right?
3. Whatelse do I do if I want to use Eclipse IDE to start coding? Like what paths, etc do I set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 32-bit ODBC as well.  Check out this link:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/03/16/32-bit-odbc-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

I think you'll be able to work through your other questions once you overcome this hurdle.

Comment: I am completely 32-bit. Office is 32 bit, Windows 7 is 32 bit. Plus, the SysWOW folder does not exist

Comment: @LittleChild Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Windows?

Comment: 32 bit Windows. I stated this earlier :) and it is working fine so I am accepting your answer as correct :)